# My repository access died when I used CVS2SVN?

Tags: apache, svn, ssl, cvs2svn

I had a problem running CVS2SVN on my server.  I have run it successfully before but I got a sort error in pass 5 so this time I added a sort option that pointed to a sort program on my system. (`sort="C:/cygwin/bin/sort.exe"`). It worked great and CVS2SVN appeared to complete successfully. So I went to my desktop to check out the files (`svn co file:///C:/repo_name`) and I got this error:

> svn: unable to open an ra_local session to url. svn: Unable to open
>   repository 'file:///C:/repo_name'

When I tried to access my other repositories I got the same message.  I checked the Apache log file and I found these messages:

> The Apache2.2 service is restarting. Starting the Apache2.2 service. 
>   The Apache2.2 service is running. Init: Session Cache is not
>   configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
>
> [Wed Oct 26 15:37:33 2011] [warn] pid file C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/Apache Software **Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/httpd.pid
>   overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?**
>
> [Wed Oct 26 15:37:40 2011] [error] Internal error: pcfg_openfile()
>   called with NULL filename
>
> [Wed Oct 26 15:37:40 2011] [error] [client 147.16.148.223] (9)Bad file
>   descriptor: Could not open password file: (null)
>
> [Wed Oct 26 15:38:37 2011] [error] [client 147.17.209.173]
>   (20014)Internal error: Can't open file 'c:\projects\svn\format':
>   The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> [Wed Oct 26 15:38:37 2011] [error] [client 147.17.209.173] Could not
>   fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
>
> [Wed Oct 26 15:38:37 2011] [error] [client 147.17.209.173] Could not
>   open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #720002]

I have found that if I log on to the server I can check out the files but I when I try to check them back in I get

> Error: Commit failed (details follow):  Error: Could not open the
>   requested SVN filesystem

Prior to this, I had been trying to get SSL certificates working on my server and had been changing options in my Apache httpd file.  It is currently set to the bare minimum with only one Virtual host *:80 and the following:

```
<Location /svn > 
  DAV svn 
  SVNListParentPath on
  SVNPath "c:\projects\svn"
  AuthName "Subversion repository (Basic)"
  AuthType Basic
</Location>

<Location /webSVN/>
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository (web)"
</Location>
```

I commented out the Include ssl.conf line that brings in all the SSL settings.

Please help!  I need to be able to access my repositories from my desktop!

Comment: Voting to move to serverfault.com, you're more likely to get an answer there.